# Failed to parse by applying lubridate dmy

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data frame where Date structure is as below: 
Factor w/ 136 levels "1/1/2016","1/1/2017",

When i convert it to as.character and then apply dmy (lubridate). it says 66581 failed to parse
When i convert it without changing it to character, same error

Code:

```
hotel$DATE <- as.character(hotel$DATE)
hotel$DATE <- dmy(hotel$DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

I have tried doing `%m%d%Y` as well. but thats not the issue

its a basic problem but its killing me! can you help?

Comment: If you are using `lubridate` you don't need to specify format. Try `hotel$DATE <- dmy(hotel$DATE)` or with `hotel$DATE <- as.Date(hotel$DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")` assuming you have dates of format `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: @RonakShah now it says: 19568 failed to parse.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there are other dates with different date formats,
you can use this,

```
library(lubridate)
hotel$DATE <-parse_date_time(hotel$DATE,c("%d/%m/%Y","other format"))]
```

Comment: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Unknown formats supplied: otefot
Giving this error on the said code

Comment: i did it without other format, and it worked. You guys are a life saver! thank you so much